# LSTM - Multiclass classification - Data prep

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification

Im trying to implement a LSTM neural net, for classify land use/cover. My dataset looks like:
[image]

So, I have around 10 k polygons (Each one has an unique New_id value), for each polygon I have calculated 4 indexes(VV,VH,RVI and RATIO) in 29 different dates (data column). I want to use a sequence of 29 dates for that 4 indexes to predict the Class (many outputs and one input). However, Im completely lost in preparing the dataset, so far I tried:
[image]

But I dont think its right... btw its returning an error when I try to run that cell:
[image]

Does anyone have any idea about what could be happening and how can I prep the dataset for this problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: Please don't give code as screenshot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
There were empty values in the dataset, so it wasnot running at first place.
Second, downgrade numpy version to 1.19.2 and it worked.